# how to display extjs 3.4 grid cells vertically

Tags: javascript, extjs

i have grid in Column Model, i want to display grid cell vertically rather than horizontally  like this : http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/view/data-view.html ; here is my code

```
    Ext.onReady(function(){  
    var data = [
    ['myNewdata'],
    ['myNewdata'],
    ['myNewdata'],          
    ];   
    var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: [
    { name: "state",type: "string"}             
    ],
    data: data
    });  
    Cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    defaults: {
    sortable: true
    },
    columns:[
    { header: "State",dataIndex: "state" },         
    ]
    });  
    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    renderTo:Ext.getBody(),    
    autoHeight: true,
    ds : store,
    cm:Cm,
    }); 
    });
```

Can you please tell me how to display it ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question. The grid comes vertically than horizontal. I guess you need vertical itself. http://jsfiddle.net/vinodgubbala/RyjxA/2/

Comment: now i am getting first row in next line second row and so on. . ! where as i want first row in next column second row.   and so on   something like this.. ! http://myshirditour.com/tem/grid.JPG ( i created pic for your ref) so please tell me. !

Comment: or plz see this too.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277146/how-to-display-extjs-3-4-grid-cells-horizontally